# strace: What do consecutive <unfinished...> syscall with no <resumed> mean?

Tags: python, linux, operating-system, system-calls, strace

I'm trying to debug a multithreaded network server written in Python with `strace -tt -f`, and the strace output makes me confused because there appear to be multiple consecutive syscalls with `<unfinished...>` on the same thread, and no resumed is observed after that:

```
9675  22:58:28.407844 <... recvfrom resumed> "\22RT\21Q\0\n", 7, 0, NULL, NULL) = 7
9675  22:58:28.518079 recvfrom(3, "\22RV\21Q\3\n", 7, 0, NULL, NULL) = 7
9675  22:58:28.518672 sendto(7, "\0\0\0\6\0\22RV\21Q\0\n", 12, 0, NULL, 0) = 12
9675  22:58:28.536676 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, 0 <unfinished ...>
9675  22:58:28.536739 <... poll resumed> ) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
9675  22:58:28.538515 recvfrom(7,  <unfinished ...>
9675  22:58:28.539400 recvfrom(7,  <unfinished ...>
9675  22:58:28.539768 sendto(7, "\0\0\0\6\0\22RW\21Q\0\n", 12, 0, NULL, 0 <unfinished ...>
9675  22:58:28.540629 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, 0 <unfinished ...>
9675  22:58:28.540666 <... poll resumed> ) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}])
9675  22:58:28.541170 recvfrom(7,  <unfinished ...>
9675  22:58:28.542603 recvfrom(7,  <unfinished ...>
9675  22:58:28.543449 shutdown(7, SHUT_RDWR <unfinished ...>
9675  22:58:28.544451 close(7 <unfinished ...>
9656  22:58:28.555189 accept4(5, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(38282), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16], SOCK_CLOEXEC) = 7
9656  22:58:28.555288 ioctl(7, FIONBIO, [0]) = 0
9656  22:58:28.555338 ioctl(7, FIONBIO, [0]) = 0
9656  22:58:28.555749 getpeername(7, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(38282), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
9656  22:58:28.555810 getsockname(7, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(6000), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
9656  22:58:28.555929 getpeername(7, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(38282), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
9675  22:58:28.560799 sendto(7, "\0\0\0\10\0\22QP\21R\21Q\2\n", 14, 0, NULL, 0) = 14
```

Comment: I think some logs are drop here app is running too fast

Comment: try examining a single syscall at the time using option -e

Comment: @OznOg Thanks. I'll try again with `perf trace`, which seems to be faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @OznOg's suggestion, it's because the multi-threaded application is running too fast thus strace drops some results.

As a better alternative, I switched to the faster `perf trace ./app` and problem was solved. Note that if you see `perf trace` complaining `ignored trace`, you can simply increase event buffer size by `sudo sh -c "echo 1032 > /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_mlock_kb"`

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the socket you are trying to get data from using the " recvfrom " is open and is returning data because it looks like your thread got stuck at that point as no data was returned back by the socket.

Also try adding exception handling to the code to debug it better.

Comment: If `recvfrom` never returns, how can 9675 call `shutdown` after it?